# How can I tracking link clicks dynamically with google analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

My html code like this :

```
<ul id="sticky-tab" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    @foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item in _stickyMenu.Children)
    {
        <li class="content accent-4  z-depth-2 @item.Fields[Templates.Navigable.Fields.CustomClass]" data-color="@item.Fields[Templates.Navigable.Fields.CustomClass]">
            <a class="@classTriger" href="@(popupID==string.Empty?item.LinkFieldUrl(Templates.Link.Fields.Link).ToString():popupID)">
                <div class="text">@item.Fields[Templates.Navigable.Fields.NavigationTitle]</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

If it generated, the result like this :

```
<ul id="sticky-tab" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li class="content accent-4  z-depth-2 red" data-color="red">
        <a class="" href="/Specialties/menu1">
            <div class="icon"><img src="" /></div>
            <div class="text">menu 1</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="content accent-4  z-depth-2 " data-color="">
        <a class="" href="/Contents/menu2">
            <div class="icon"><img src="" /></div>
            <div class="text">menu 2</div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="content accent-4  z-depth-2 " data-color="">
        <a class="" href="/Contents/menu3">
            <div class="icon"><img src=""/> </div>
            <div class="text">menu 3</div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to tracking link click with google analytics. I try like this :

```
  <a class="@classTriger" href="@(popupID==string.Empty?item.LinkFieldUrl(Templates.Link.Fields.Link).ToString():popupID)" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'a', 'click');">
        <div class="text">@item.Fields[Templates.Navigable.Fields.NavigationTitle]</div>
    </a>
```

But, it does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In the real-time report you did not see any event-type interaction after you clicked on the link?

Comment: What version of tracking code are you using? analytics.js or gtag.js?

Comment: @BronwynV it's gtag.js

Comment: @SuccessMan you are using analytics.js event tracking syntax not gtag.js event tracking syntax https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

Comment: @BronwynV Okay thanks